# How can I make my File Upload button have a hover state?

Tags: html, css, hover

I was able to customize a file upload button with CSS in my site, but for some reason I cannot change it's background color in its `hover` state. Everything else works just fine.

I tried the usual `:hover` property but it doesn't work.
Here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/GRRZMZO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the

```
.btn-img-upload:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

to

```
.btn-block:hover .btn-img-upload{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm using the class `btn-block`in other buttons. This won't affect the rest, correct?

Comment: Do you have any other hover effects on `.btn-block` ?

Comment: If you have btn-block somewhere else in the same page it will change the upload button to red. if you have multiple btn-block in the same page add a class on this btn-block only and make the hover to that class >>>>>> .newclass:hover .btn-img-upload